# Secure a firebase hosting link to only be accessible from a specific ip

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-hosting

I am using angular 4 angularfire 2 and firebase in an web app. I am conditionate to use firebase as a backend service and because the app has to only be used inside the office i am wondering if there is any way i can configure some firebase rules or anything to make the app not work or be shown from another ip than the office ip. Please leave any kind of way i can do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to restrict access to a site deployed to Firebase Hosting.  It will always be accessible from anywhere in the world that is not blocked by some other firewall.